# There is any function for image cropping basing on svg annotation in Cairo python?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, svg, python-2.7, cairo

I have JPG images and with inputsvgdraw, a flash tool for image annotation (http://www.mainada.net/inputdraw).

As Gimp or Picasa, when i crop an image and i save as new image only the cropped part. I need a function that take svg path (representing new image bourders) as parameter and then basing on that, create the new image.

svg data:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 488 325"><g fill="none"   stroke-miterlimit="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path d="M 307 97 l 0 -1 l -2 -1 l -10 -2 l -20 -1 l -25 5 l -22 9 l -10 9 l 0 9 l 2 12 l 16 18 l 25 11 l 25 5 l 17 -1 l 6 -4 l 3 -7 l -1 -12 l -6 -16 l -7 -13 l -11 -12 l -11 -14 l -9 -5" opacity="1" stroke="rgb(170,37,34)" stroke-width="5"/></g></svg>.
```

How can i extract and save in a new image inside circle part image? There is any library that handle this?
There is a way convert these datas for a function in a image library in python and cropping image?

Comment: Clarify what do you mean by "How can i extract and save in a new image inside circle part image?". As for the operation performed there, I believe `cairo` could handle it easily.

Comment: Like Gimp or Picasa, when i crop an image and i save as new image only the cropped part. I need a function that take svg path (representing new image bourders) as parameter and then basing on that, create the new image.